# Sublime Text 3 Python3 build not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have just installed the latest version of Sublime Text 3 on my Linux Pop_!OS Computer but I cannot run a python file.

When I try to build the file with python with `CTRL-B` it gives me an error in the logs...

```
bash: python: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/media/kevinapetrei/KEVIN USB/Files/Programming/Python Programs/Finished/HiLo Versions/HiLo-2.02/setup.py"]
[dir: /media/kevinapetrei/KEVIN USB/Files/Programming/Python Programs/Finished/HiLo Versions/HiLo-2.02]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

This is pretty weird because I installed a package on terminal which allows me to use command `python` to run python3. (In terminal I can still run files using command `python`.

What is wrong? Can I edit this to make it work somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `build system` for python3 on Linux if the built-in method is not working.

First, open your terminal and write

```
$ which python3
```

it will give you the location of python3

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Then in sublime text go to `tools -> Build System -> New Build System` and paste below code in that file and change location of the python if it is in a different location:

```
{
 "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Now save it using `anyname_you_want.sumblime-build` and open a python file then select `tools -> Build System -> anyname_you_want` and run your python file. It should work.

Comment: changing the `file_regex` to `" "^[ ]*File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)""` allows sublime text to visually track which lines have errors (at least on sublimetext on ubuntu). got that from @MattDMo at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71630337/6794367